# How to programatically (java) prevent specific errors messages to be sent to Sentry

Tags: java, sentry

How to programatically (java) prevent specific errors messages to be sent to Sentry? I want, for example, do not send to Sentry errors with the word "any_example_word". It's important to know that filtering by error message is not enabled in the User Interface.

I'm using Sentry 1.7.23, but all examples I can find use latest version (4.*), which are tottaly different. They use classes and methods that do not exist in this old version.

I don't know if this is relevant, but my application runs over thorntail and it uses jdk 8.

**Edit:**
I'm trying to do this:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static SentryClient sentryClient = SentryClientFactory.sentryClient();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Sentry.init();

        String testStrings = "ipsis litteris;some_error_message";
        String[] messagesToIgnore = StringUtils.split(testStrings, ';');

        sentryClient.addShouldSendEventCallback(new ShouldSendEventCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSend(Event event) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, SentryInterface> interfaceEntry : event.getSentryInterfaces().entrySet()) {
                    if (interfaceEntry.getValue() instanceof ExceptionInterface) {
                        ExceptionInterface i = (ExceptionInterface) interfaceEntry.getValue();
                        for (SentryException sentryException : i.getExceptions()) {
                            for (String msgToIgnore : messagesToIgnore) {
                                if (StringUtils.contains(sentryException.getExceptionMessage(), msgToIgnore)) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        Sentry.setStoredClient(sentryClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Question 1) Is this the correct place to initialize Sentry?
Question 2) Why `ShouldSendEventCallback` is lost? Looking at
`io.sentry.SentryClient`:

```
public void sendEvent(Event event) {
    for (ShouldSendEventCallback shouldSendEventCallback : shouldSendEventCallbacks) {
        if (!shouldSendEventCallback.shouldSend(event)) {
            logger.trace("Not sending Event because of ShouldSendEventCallback: {}", shouldSendEventCallback);
            return;
        }
    }

    try {
        connection.send(event);
    } catch (LockedDownException | TooManyRequestsException e) {
        logger.debug("Dropping an Event due to lockdown: " + event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("An exception occurred while sending the event to Sentry.", e);
    } finally {
        getContext().setLastEventId(event.getId());
    }
}
```

In some point during app execution, `sentryClient` is reinitialized and `shouldSendEventCallbacks` becomes empty, what causes my messages not being filtered.
So I get back to question 1, since apparently sentry configuration is not being persistent.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from upgrading to 4.0?

Comment: Yes, support team needs to evaluate impacts on other applications and support services. There is no expectation to upgrade it for at least 3 months (when they say "at least", please multiply by 3 "at least"... lol)